# Opening index.html over file:// from Vue-cli template

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, vue.js

When I run `npm run build` command, from [this Vue-cli template](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack), it says:

> Tip: built files are meant to be served over an HTTP server.
>
> Opening index.html over file:// won't work.

So, the question is simple, is there any possibility, to open *index.html* with *file://*, and it will works?

Comment: Maybe, but why do you want to?

Comment: @akatakritos I want to send it to users, who aren't technically advanced, they need simply open html file in browser, enough for them.

Comment: It's possible, you'll need to adjust all the asset urls in `index.html`. I think the default urls start with `/static`, change them to `static`. Source:  i tried it once and it worked.

Comment: @EricGuan Thank's, I'll try!

Answer (score 0):

Change assetsPublicPath to './', then "npm run build", and then you can open file:// in your browser.

```
  build: {
    // Template for index.html
    index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'),

    // Paths
    assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: './',
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this solution too.